# Columns overlapping while using grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm using the `grid` layout in CSS and my aim is to have an image, text, an input field and a button next to each other, spanning over two rows as illustrated here:

[image]

I've given the image the `grid-column` property of `1 / 1` so that it is only in the first column, and all the other elements have `2 / 2` so that they are in the second column.

The problem I'm facing is that the second column is overlapping the first column, as seen in this snippet:

```css
.profile {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.profile>*:not(img) {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.sameline {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nr3C7T/pic.png">
    <div class="sameline">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <button>Click</button>
    </div>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="text">
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try running your code twice

Comment: Idk why that behavior is there on running it the second time

Comment: @Arex That's strange why does it fix its self on the second run?

Comment: What happens when you run the complete code?

Comment: *"I've given the image the `grid-column` property of `1 / 1` so that it is only in the first column..."* ... That interpretation is incorrect. `grid-column: 1 / 1` is a shorthand rule that means *create a grid area that spans from `grid-column-start: 1` to `grid-column-end: 1`*. So basically, you haven't even created a column. `grid-column-end` must be `2`. So this is what you want: `grid-column: 1 / 2`.

Comment: More details here: [Why is my grid item not spanning multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50219916/3597276)

Comment: @Michael_B Hi Michael, I've amended my code. When you run the snippet, the issue is there. But if you click run again, it resolves its self. I think this has something to do with a delay in the image loading. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

All you had to do was increase  `grid-column-gap`. This makes them non overlapping. Change the styling to suit your needs.

```css
.profile {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 100px;
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.profile>*:not(img) {
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
}

.sameline {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nr3C7T/pic.png">
    <div class="sameline">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <button>Click</button>
    </div>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="text" style="width:100%;">
    </form>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Isn't that more a work around, rather than a fix to the problem, because the columns shouldn't overlap even if the gap between them was 0?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but I think what you mean is that the second column in the second row is overlapping.

The grid-row property is not correctly used in this case. This property works with grid lines. So the first value is used to specify from which grid line the item starts, and the second one specifies the grid line where it should end. So in your case, you say that it should start from grid line 1 (so essentially the top border of the grid) and that it should end at grid line 2 (which is the grid line between the two columns).

What you actually want is for the image to start at grid line 1 and end at grid line 3, so that it covers both of rows. The same rule applies to the grid-column property.

```css
.profile {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 100px;
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.profile>*:not(img) {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.sameline {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nr3C7T/pic.png">
    <div class="sameline">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <button>Click</button>
    </div>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="text">
    </form>
  </div>
```